# Display values in ListView using ObjectDataProvider

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, listview

Hello all i'm trying to find out why my `ListView` is loading in blank.

i've made a `ObjectDataProvider` that load from my controller a list of `Articulos` in a `DataTable`

**TrabajarArticulos.cs**

```
namespace ClasesBase
{
    public class TrabajarArticulos
    {
        public static DataTable TraerArticulos()
        {
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ClasesBase.Properties.Settings.Default.conexion);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Articulo";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);           
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

**Articulos.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="lista_articulos" ObjectType="{x:Type svc:TrabajarArticulos}" MethodName="TraerArticulos"></ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

This is used on the same windows in a `ListView`

```
<ListView Name="ListArt" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=lista_articulos}}"
              Margin="360,61,22,184">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Art_Id}"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Descripcion" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Art_Descrip}"></GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>                    
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

But when it loads it's blank (not empty) [Example](http://image.prntscr.com/image/50a685d0bbec45dea0492953f2cb1fe9.jpeg)

My first thought was it couldn't load, but making a debug with `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` i can see the values of my array.

Also tried to use `DataContext` instead of `ItemsSource` but still with no result.

Even thought i was binding them wrong on the `GridViewColumn` but still no luck.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

**EDIT** i've noticed that if i add manually my object `Articulo` it shows good. And now let me more  lost in what is wrong.

```
ListArt.Items.Add(articulo);
```

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to jstreet for his feedback, i found the problem that was very basic.

All the `ColumnName` from the `DataTable` were in lowercase and not in uppercase as my model.

So the `GridViewColumn` should be like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=art_id}"></GridViewColumn>
<GridViewColumn Header="Descripcion" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=art_descrip}"></GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: See it with `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=lista_articulos}}"/>` .

Comment: i've tried that and still displaying empty

Comment: Return `System.Data.DataView` from your method and use `return dt.DefaultView` ; And then use it with `DataGrid` .

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on your `TrabajarArticulos` implementation . Here's some working sample code:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication286.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication286"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>

    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Source1" 
                        ObjectType="{x:Type local:MyDataTable}">
    </ObjectDataProvider>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=Source1}}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}"></GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

**DataTable:**

```
public class MyDataTable : DataTable
{
    public MyDataTable()
    {
        Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));

        for (int i = 1001; i <= 1005; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = NewRow();
            row["ID"] = i;
            row["Description"] = string.Format("Data item from table {0}", i);
            Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Please note `ObjectDataProvider` is meant to be a `Resource`. If you're going to be dynamically populating it at run time..., perhaps you'd be better off just sticking with a standard `MVVM` approach. Nonetheless, for our testing purposes here, retrieving data from my local DB still works same way:

**XAML:**

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Source1" 
                        ObjectType="{x:Type local:MyDataTable}"
                        MethodName="GetDbData">
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

**DataTable:**

```
public DataTable GetDbData()
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(con);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Production.Product";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = cnn;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            DataRow row = NewRow();
            row["ID"] = dr["ProductID"];
            row["Description"] = dr["Name"];
            Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return this;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: My datatable, comes from a database, i'll update my post to make it clear

Comment: Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: sorry the dumb question, but what is `NewRow()` ? i've assumed that's `new Row()` but can't find the reference to import it.

Comment: `NewRow()` is a method in `DataTable`. Look [Here - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Oh thanks, i've just read that, when i made the `Rows.add(row)` it's being applied in `dt` ?

Comment: If you want to make sure is adding rows to your `dt` variable, then you should do `dt.Rows.Add(row)`.

Comment: Ok, your answer wasn't the correct, but lead me to find out what was my problem. Thank you soo much for your help

Comment: OK, post what the problem was and your solution then, so others can benefit from it.